# embed external web site's content in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What techniques can be used in embed an external web site's content in ASP.NET MVC's contentplaceholder?  It is similar to ASP's iFrame.  I know how to host the first page but I can not figure out how to make the linked pages in the external site stay in contentplaceholder of MVC application.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why can't you just use an iFrame?

Comment: @trebuchet Thanks for your quick response.  iFrame works for MVC too?  I thought it was phrased out.  Any good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe is completely valid HTML, thus it is completely valid in an MVC app.

Just place an iframe in the contentplaceholder and assign it's `src` attribute to the desired URL.

Comment: The first URL can be assigned in this way.  But when users click the links in the external website, how can they all stay in the MVC pages?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - If the external website is loaded in an iframe, the user is able to navigate the site within that iframe

Comment: You are right.  I am confused with myself since I have not used iFrame for so long.  It works simply putting iframe in contentplaceholder.  Thanks again